# HttpRuntime.Cache doesn't appear to be working

Tags: asp.net, caching, httpruntime.cache

I am trying to build a system to list items within my Back office system on eBay via the eBay ASP.NET SDK.

Since loading eBay categories isn't terribly fast, and infrequently changing, I figured I'd cache the responses from the requests I'll make.

I have a function which returns a list of eBay categories as an eBay `CategoryTypeCollection` and I am trying to Cache it, then check for it and retrieve new if necessary:

```
Dim CategoryList As New CategoryTypeCollection
If HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("eBayCategories") Is Nothing Then
    CategoryList = Categories.DisplayCategories()
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("eBayCategories", CategoryList, Nothing, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0))
Else
    CategoryList = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("eBayCategories")
End If
```

However, it is always getting new data.

This is part of a much bigger project, and caching is working for other things, I can't see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The cache is expiring immediately because you specify 0 minutes to expire.

Change it to `Cache.NoSlidingExpiration` instead.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("eBayCategories", connectionString, Nothing, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration)
```

See [MSDN Cache.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: I hope you're right, but I am sure I tried that... will report back!

Comment: :-( Modified as above and still it's fetching new data every time I load the page.

Comment: Edit - After a bit more experimentation it seems that loading the categories from the eBay API is clearing my cache! It's clearing my Session Data too, almost resetting the server memory.